# Generalization of Minkowski theorem

Tags: geometry, geometry-of-numbers

Can you help proving this generalization of [the Minkowski theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski%27s_theorem#Proof) ?

> Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^N$ be a nonempty centrally symmetric convex subset.
>
> a) Then $\#(\Omega \cap \mathbb{Z}^N) \ge 2 (\lceil \frac{Vol(\Omega)}{2^N}\rceil-1)+1$
>
> b) If $\Omega$ is closed and bounded, then $\#(\Omega \cap \mathbb{Z}^N) \ge 2 \lfloor \frac{Vol(\Omega)}{2^N}\rfloor+1$

Comment: It is important to avoid the use of pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures cannot be searched 
and are inaccessible to those using screen readers; please [edit] the question to correct that and include your 
thoughts and the work you have done so far to solve the problem. If you need it, here is some basic information 
about writing math on MSE:
[here](/help/notation),
[here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and 
[here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Did you look at [this sketch proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski%27s_theorem#Proof) when $\lceil Vol(\Omega) / 2^N \rceil = 1$. I'd say we can adapt it replacing the map $(\bmod 2, \bmod 2)$ by a map $(\bmod n, \bmod m)$

Comment: @user1952009 I don't think, since that would would require an exponential change in the volume, not multiplicative.

Comment: Click on edit to see the latex I typed. @InfiniteMonkey

Comment: @user1952009 Thank you!

Comment: Otherwise you can try to divide $\Omega$ into $m$ pieces, symmetric about some different lattice points. I'd say we should start with $\lceil Vol(\Omega) / 2^N \rceil = 2$

Comment: @user1952009 hmmm I don't exactl see what you mean, could you clarify?

Comment: @user1952009 Oh I see! we make pizzas in angles that just go over volume 2^n!

Comment: @user1952009 If you want to write this as an answer I'll accept it. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You found a solution ? I didn't. Can you explain in the simplest case ($2$ pieces ?). You need to make it centrallly symmetric and convex, but you can move your pieces on the lattice

Comment: @user1952009 sorry my idea doesn't work, it won't be convex :(

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in here:
http://www.fmf.uni-lj.si/~lavric/Shmonin%20-%20Minkowski%27s%20theorem%20and%20its%20applications.pdf

The idea is just instead of 2 vectors with difference that is an integer vector we must have $m$ of those (where the volume is $m*2^n$)